# Open Java DB database in OpenOffice Base or Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access, derby, openoffice-base

I created a database in NetBeans, and I was wondering if it was possible to open it in OpenOffice or Access for easier ease of use. The database is stored locally. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In order to open the database using Microsoft Access you would need to have an ODBC driver for Derby (Java DB). Access does ODBC but it does not "do" JDBC.

However, OpenOffice/LibreOffice Base *does* in fact "do" JDBC so you could simply use the same JDBC driver (JAR file) that you used with NetBeans JDBC to open the database in OpenOffice/LibreOffice Base via JDBC.

Comment: I tried connecting to the JDBC database through OpenOffice base, but it I got an error that said the JDBC driver could not be loaded.

Comment: @BradleyPearl - You probably need to add the Derby JAR file to the "Class Path" for OpenOffice. See instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/519571/323236) for details. (Those instructions refer to a UCanAccess JAR file, but you would add the Derby JAR file instead.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JDBC to access a Derby database programmatically.

However, there are command-line tools that access a Derby database, for example Derby's own `ij` tool as well as others.

Many other software packages have the ability to "call out" to a command-line tool. If either OpenOffice or Microsoft Access have the ability to "call out" to a command-line tool, you should be able to have them call out to `ij` (or any other JDBC command-line tool of your choice) to access the data you want.

For example, you could invoke `ij`, have it run a simple script that called `SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_DATA` to export some table data to a csv file, then import that csv file into OpenOffice or Microsoft Access.